# How to write integer value "60" in 16bit binary, 32bit binary & 64bit binary

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

How to write integer value `"60"` in other binary formats?

`8bit` binary code of `60` = `111100`

`16bit` binary code of `60` = ?

`32bit` binary code of `60` = ?

`64bit` binary code of `60` = ?

is it `111100000000` for 16 bit binary?

why does 8bit binary code contain 6bits instead of 8?

I googled for the answers but I'm not able to get these answers. Please provide answers as I'm still a beginner of this area.

Comment: The bit width zeros are always prefixed from the standpoint if binary.  If you are asking about storage it would depend on the endian

Comment: The binary representation of `60` is always going to be `111100`, period. It is 6 bits instead of 8 because it only takes 6 bits to represent that value. It still only takes 6 bits if you're using 16, 32, or 64 bit values to store the contents. If it got padded to a certain width, it would be left-padded with zeros, but `00111100` is still `111100`. A 16-bit binary value of `111100000000` would be `3840` decimal. (Using Windows, you can check this yourself. Start Calculator, View->Programmers, and you can see both hex and binary, different bits (Byte=8, Word=16, Dword=32, and Qword=64.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imagine you're writing the decimal value `60`. You can write it using 2 digits, 4 digits or 8 digits:

```
1. 60
2. 0060
3. 00000060
```

In our decimal notation, the most significant digits are to the left, so increasing the number of digits for representation, without changing the value, means just adding zeros to the left.

Now, in most binary representations, this would be the same. The decimal 60 needs only 6 bits to represent it, so an 8bit or 16bit representation would be the same, except for the left-padding of zeros:

```
1. 00111100
2. 00000000 00111100
```

**Note:** Some OSs, software, hardware or storage devices might have different [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) - which means they might store 16bit values with the least significant byte first, then the most signficant byte. Binary notation is still MSB-on-the-left, as above, but reading the memory of such little-endian devices will show any 16bit chunk will be internally reversed:

```
1. 00111100 - 8bit - still the same.
2. 00111100 00000000 - 16bit, bytes are flipped.
```

Answer (score 3):

every number has its own binary number, that means that there is only one!
on a 16/32/64 bit system 111100 - 60 would just look the same with many 0s added infront of the number (regulary not shown)
so on 16 bit it would be 0000000000111100
32 bit - 0000000000000000000000000011110
and so on

Comment: Oh and 111100 are just the bits you need for the number to be shown, so actualy on 8 bits 60 is 00111100

Answer (score 0):

For storage [Endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) matters ... otherwise bitwidth zeros are always prefixed so 60 would be...

```
8bit:  00111100
16bit: 0000000000111100
```